# What is %windir%?

Tags: home-directory, home-folder

What does `%windir%` stands for?

I am receiving a malware analysis report with things like `%windir%\system32\catroot`, `%windir%\folder1\folder2` and I want to know what does it mean?

Comment: C:\WINDOWS is highly likely. ;)

Comment: %windir% is an environment variable for the windows path so its just a 'shortcut' to C:\windows or wherever you installed windows...

Comment: -1 because Googling "What is %windir%?" gives you plenty of correct info in the first matches.

Comment: +1 because Googling "What is %windir%?" gives this question and answer without all the superfluous stuff on other results.

Comment: +1 because I think this site is *exactly* the right kind of place you should up on when googling this type of question.

Answer (score 11):

The Windows directory or SYSROOT. This corresponds to the `%WINDIR%` or `%SYSTEMROOT%` environment variables. A typical path is `C:\Windows`.

> This variable points to the Windows directory (on Windows NT-based
>   operating systems it is identical to the %SystemRoot% variable. If the
>   system is on drive C:, then the default values are "C:\WINDOWS" on
>   Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows Me, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003,
>   Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7.

For more info see Wikipedia's [Environment Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) entry.

Answer (score 8):

Open a command prompt by clicking Start, typing `cmd`, then Enter. Type `echo %windir%`, then Enter, and the path should print to the screen. Usually `C:\WINDOWS`

Comment: WOW, thank you so much for posting this. There are many questions out there asking about what the various system variables are, and this is the first answer I have seen that tells you how to actually see what path the variable represents. `echo %windir%`. Now that I see it, I understand how simple it is, but I'm not a sys admin so I knew it had to be something easy, but wasn't sure what it was. Thanks again.